# Domain redirect and rewrite with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

If a my site is `www.example.com` and a user types in `www.example.com/robert` I would like to display the page at `www.example.com/users?user=robert`. Basically I want to create a profile page for each user but I want it to be accessible by simply typing the username after the domain as a directory.

How can I do this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /users.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```